# Euler Identity value of $0^0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I heard a graduate student say that if 0 is raised to the 0 it grows so exponentially big that it actually becomes one. He said it had something to do with Eulers Identity.

I have found very similar discussions on the site involving Taylor series and supposedly getting 1 at the end. The argument for $0^0 = 0,1$ or undefined seems almost religious.

Is there any truth to his statement? He did not show us any proofs as he said it was outside of our jurisdiction for a differential equations class. Just curious

Comment: It is a matter of definition. Either you define $0^0=1$ or you leave it undefined. Since you haven't given the Euler identity argument, I can't figure out what that is about, or why it is in the title. Otherwise, this is a question that has been asked and answered many times here. There is no mathematician who seriously argues for defining $0^0=0$.

Comment: Also, do you mean Euler's identity of Euler product? The Euler product (in your tag) is different from Euler's identity.

Comment: I apologize I picked the wrong tag I meant Euler identity not the product

Comment: Are you sure the graduate student wasn't saying something like, $0^0$ is undefined since some paths towards the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}x^y$ grow large quickly whereas other paths go to $1$?

Answer (score 2):

We have $\lim\limits_{x\to0}x^x=1.~$ Letting $x=\dfrac1n$ , this is equivalent to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]n=1,~$ which can be shown by taking the logarithm, and applying [l'Hopital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'Hopital's_rule).

Comment: But $\lim_{x,y \to 0^+} x^y$ is undefined;  $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^0 = 1$ and $\lim_{y \to 0^+} 0^y = 0$.  There is no obvious reason why we should take $y = x$ before evaluating the limit.

Comment: @CarlMummert: Actually, there is such a reason, since this convention usually appears in situations such as $\sum a_n$, where $a_n$ might contain $n^n$ in its expression.

Answer (score 1):

$0^0$ is defined as $1$. But regardless of the intuition, I think you might be referring to it as an indeterminate form which is what most people have trouble with. The following two limits are both indeterminate of form $0^0$, but they have different results.

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x^0=1$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}0^x=0$

So, when looking at two limits as follows, the order matters

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}x^y=1$

$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x^y=0$

This may be what they were referring to.

Comment: $0^0$ is defined as $1$ in the context of natural number exponentiation. But, for example, in the context of complex exponentiation we would have $0^0 = \exp(0\log 0)$ which is undefined due to the $\log 0$ term.